# Confused with the variable in js

Tags: javascript, variables

```
function Person(name){
    var age;
    this.name = name;
    this.setAge = function(a){
        age = a;
    }
    this.getAge = function(){
        return age;
    }
}
var p0 = new Person("John");
p0.setAge(24);
console.log("p0.getAge "+p0.getAge());//p0.getAge 24
var p1 = new Person("Mike")
p1.setAge("25");
console.log("p0.getAge "+p0.getAge());//I think the output here should be p0.getAge 25,but it is p0.getAge 24
console.log("p1.getAge "+p1.getAge());//p0.getAge 25
```

The variable "age" does not belong to any instance of Person as there is no "this.age" in the constructor of Person and it should be shared by instance of Person at first, But the result is not what i expected. I'm confused!

Comment: `age`, in your case, is just the equivalent of a ` private ` variable. You won't be able to directly access it outside the object (despite you can `edit` its value using the `setAge` function), but it still belongs to the object itself, it's not shared.

Answer (score 3):

```
function Person(name){
    var age;
    this.name = name;
    this.setAge = function(a){
        age = a;
    }
    this.getAge = function(){
        return age;
    }
}
```

look  `var age;`, you dont declare `this.age`, this is particularly done when you dont want variable directly accessed from outside, i.e. you try to make it private for that object, that is why you don't create a property for the object, but just a variable for that closure.

Still you can access it inside the object and return it using `getAge` method, but not directly with age. so there is no property `age`, but there exists a variable `age`

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you said: age is like a private variable and can not be accessed outside the function Person.But from the perspective of closure, the age belongs to the context(or variable object) of function Person.When we call setAge using p0 and p1 respectively, they manipulate the same age in the variable object of function Person.Where is the problem of my understanding?

Comment: yes age belongs to the context of person function, and each of its created objects: as they are functions too

Comment: Actually, I kind of feeling that I have problem in understanding of the variable resolving process in js.From object perspective OR closure perspective?Or more specifically, which way will happen in resolving process?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `age` "property" was not implicitly declared as an instance variable, but its scope is contained within the function. And each time you call your `setAge()` method, it sets the new value for the `age` variable, if you don't call `setAge()` on the object, the `age` will be undefined which is the default value for un-initialized variables. It is not a global variable, therefore it is not shared across objects.

Comment: As you mentioned above,the age is contained within the function Person(),when we call setAge using p0, the age within the function Person is accessed. Then we call setAge  using p1,we still access the same age as accessed by p0,cause p0 is in the context(or variable object) of function Person.Can you point out where I misunderstand?Thank you!

Comment: I want to quote your statement `Then we call setAge using p1,we still access the same age as accessed by p0,cause p0 is in the context(or variable object) of function Person`, no `age` is defined within the `Person` constructor with the `var` keyword, so it became local to the constructor only, so each new `Person` object will get a different `age` variable, if you declared `age` WITHOUT the `var` keyword, then it WILL become a GLOBAL VARIABLE, so `age` will be shared among your objects meaning that they will have the same value for `age` which is whatever value you set on it...

Answer (score 0):

The scope of variable is in **function**, the code works fine.

If you expect a singleton variable, a variable outside or Person.age are good ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(name){
    var age; //private variable
    this.name = name;
    this.setAge = function(a){
        age = a;
    }
    this.getAge = function(){
        return age;
    }
}
```

You've made a closure. A `closure` is a private environment. Or variables declared within the closure (function) are only accessible for that function. You've create two instances of your constructor `person`. The parser made two separate objects each containing it's own private variable `age`. So when you call `setAge` on `John` his private variable `age` is updated, but the private variable for `Mike` is left untouched. The variables are only accessible in their own scope, not in the global scope. Do mind that the variable isn't connected to the instance `John`. To make the variable public you need to do this in the constructor function person: `this.age`.

For getters and setters there is a new function (available in modern browsers)

[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

An example:

```
function Person(name){
    var age; //private variable
    this.name = name;

    var age = 0;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "age", {
        get : function(){return age;}, //has access to the private var `age` in this scope.
        set : function(value){age = value;}
    });
}
```

Now when you call `John`'s age via `p0.age` you get 0. But when you do `p0.age = 10` it sets the private var `age` to 10.